# Am not able to connect to socket with HTTPS

Tags: java, android

```java
TrustManager[] trustManager = new TrustManager[]{
    new X509TrustManager() {
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new X509Certificate[0];
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificate, String str) {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificate, String str) {
        }
    }
};

SSLContext sslContext = null;
try {
    sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    try {
        sslContext.init(null, trustManager, null);
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

HostnameVerifier myHostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return true;
    }
};

SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().hostnameVerifier(myHostnameVerifier)
                                                      .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory,X509TrustManager trustManager).build();
```

am getting an error near `sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory,X509TrustManager trustManager).build();`

Comment: then Problem in your back-end. not in app. check you server SSL is correctly configured or not. https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

Comment: Thank you sir, but it seems like there is some issue with the trustManager, the exact error is in the line X509TrustManager trustManager).build();

Comment: I am not understand what is you need to do manually create `TrustManager` and applied to `OkHttpClient`

Answer (score 0):

```
 TrustManager[] trustManager = new X509TrustManager[]{
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return new X509Certificate[0];
                        }

                        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificate, 
String str) {
                        }

                        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificate, 
String str) {
                        }
                    }
            };

            SSLContext sslContext = null;
            try {
                sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                try {
                    sslContext.init(null, trustManager, null);
                } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            HostnameVerifier myHostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            };

            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().hostnameVerifier(myHostnameVerifier).sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory).build();
```